# Installed android app does not see an update published on Google Play

Tags: google-play, auto-update

I have published an android app on Google play. And later I also published an update to the market. Everything seems to be working fine. However, on phones that already installed the first version, they do not see a new update and do not install even though they checked with 'automatic install new update if available'.

I checked if the Google play published my new update and it already did. Because if I install my app on a phone that does not have the first version, I would get the updated version. When I published my update, I already changed the app version.

Anyone knows of this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be duplicate

[Android app not shown as "update available" in Market](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8853818/1721946)

This might be the answer that you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499092/1721946